# How can I get data from this image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have a website that shows me information about karting races (e.g. last lap time, best lap time, laps completed...) and I want to get this data to create a database to use on strategy of endurances. I don't want enter the data manually on a excel worksheet, so I'm trying to get a screenshot and apply an OCR to convert to text. I'm trying this way using Python and Tesseract:

```
#import libs
import pytesseract as ocr
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

#convert to RGB and keep green channel
npimagem = np.asarray(Image.open('race.png').convert('RGB')).astype(np.uint8)
npimagem[:, :, 0] = 0
npimagem[:, :, 2] = 0

#convert to gray
im = cv2.cvtColor(npimagem, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
binimagem = Image.fromarray(thresh)

text = ocr.image_to_string(binimagem, lang='eng')
```

The result is below:
*Session: F4 DRIVERS / PROVA 4 - 21:30
Timing: 00:00:00
See Cem)

21:59:34
Pee
ot

#035 ALEXANDRE CURY Fa privers

1 Cred ee ee Tg ia ee) ee SE} ri coe
P #012 PAULO ALEX ra privers
Cred ee a te eae aed Cena EES ri Pert coe Pert
3 #000 DANIEL LUTFI Fa privers
Cred ee aT em CO Best Lap: 17 en ERLE ri Cea) coe rx}
mn #046 ANDERSON SILVA Fa privers
Cred aT ee Ee [era ee) ee ER ri Ce) coe 0.200
5 Gath C10 smn 721 Or Beano)
Cred Tecate Cieza eae ese Cea RSS Diff: 10.405 coe cary
6 #032 LUIZ RUBELLO Fa privers
Cred ee aT eek ae) eee Pe esel Gap: 14.479
, #022 DANILO PACINI Fa privers
Cred ea ee Oe eae aed Corer aS eyed coe at)
8 #013 EDUARDO RECHE Fa privers
Cred ea ee Oe Best Lap: 17 Cem ee ee Py eis C) coe cared
PD #028 RAFAEL MICHELETTI ra privers
Cred eee ee te Se) ia ey em [ec] coe Cel)
10 #068 MANOEL PIMENTEL Fa privers
Cees) ee Ee ea ena ri pear CS aT

Seo Ret ee are merier|
Brought to you by Race-Monitor.com*

How can I get text more identical to the real? The image quality it's not so bad...

Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0jz.png)

Comment: If your data source is from website, I think there is a better way to use beautifulsoup in python to parse html, especially the data seems formatted.

Comment: You can try replacing THRESH_BINARY with THRESH_BINARY_INV in code.

Comment: I saved the html pages and managed to locate the data using regex